# Как вращать куб на Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css3, css, javascript

Есть два блока, которые являются двумя сторонами одного куба. Один блок скрыт по умолчанию. При нажатии на кнопку скрытый блок заменяет открытый; при этом должно создаваться впечатление, что мы повернули куб.

Скрытый

```
#hid{width:0px;display:block;position:absolute;-webkit-transform:rotateY(90deg);}
```

Блок в скрытом блоке

```
#in_hid{width:500px;background-color:#456789;}
```

Открытый

```
#ext{width:500;background-color:#987654;}
#hid,#ext{-webkit-transition:all 2s;}

<div id="cont">
   <div id="hid"><div id="in_hid">Текст</div></div>
   <div id="ext"></div>
</div>
```

При нажатии на кнопку

```
$(ext).css('transform','translateX(275px) rotateY(90deg)');
$(hid).css('transform','translateX(0px) rotateY(0deg)');
```

Но при вращении один блок налезает на другой и весь эффект портится? Как можно создать такой эффект без плагинов?

Comment: во-1, у куба шесть сторон, а не две.
во-2, для трехмерного колдунства jquery применять нездраво, это как микроскопом гвозди забивать, есть куча иных библиотек для рисования

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Демо](http://jsbin.com/qewemihe/1/edit)

Источник: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/

```
    <div id ="cub">

<a href="http://www.cisco.com/en/US/hmpgs/index.html" class="external roll-link" rel="nofollow"><span data-title="Cisco">Cisco</span></a>
</div>

#cub {margin-top:40px;}

/* ROLL LINKS */
.roll-link {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;

    vertical-align: top;

    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
       -moz-perspective: 600px;
       -ms-perspective: 600px;
       perspective: 600px;

    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
       -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
       -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
       perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  background: yellow;

}

.roll-link:hover {text-decoration:none;}

.roll-link span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 2px;

    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
       -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
       -ms-transition: all 400ms ease;
       transition: all 400ms ease;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       transform-origin: 50% 0%;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.roll-link:hover span {
        background: #e93a30;

        -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
           -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
           -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
           transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
}

.roll-link span:after {
    content: attr(data-title);

    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 2px;

    color: #fff;
    background: #e93a30;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       transform-origin: 50% 0%;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
       -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
       -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
       transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
}
```

Comment: а где здесь jQuery?..